# State of composite Higgs models

Tags: particle-physics, mass, higgs

I'm studying the analogies between U(1) Higgs model and superconductivity BCS and GL theories. The question arises when Cooper pairs seem to be the responsible of the effective mass of the photon (I mean: no superconductivity, no cooper pairs, no photon's effective mass). Cooper pairs are a composite particle, so by analogy, Higgs boson might be. I found some ''old'' models (before Higgs boson discovery) but I'm an undergraduate student and I don't understand many things, but I think some of those models are now discarded. So nowadays, which is the state of composite Higgs models?

I said 'nowadays'. As I said, I'm undergraduate, I'm starting in this field, I don't understand much the articles. I don't want details, I want to know what hypothesis are still plausible and some information about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/312032100_Brief_Introduction_to_the_Expanded_Rishon_Model) is a nice model of recent times. Look also [here](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2FBF02788166.pdf). To be more divulgative, consider the second.
In the second link the most recent attempt to envision the compositeness of the Higgs (and all other particles), sees the Higgs as composed out of rishons, first introduced by Harari in 1981. For example, the $W^{+/-}$ are composed out of three $T$ rishons and three $V$ rishons ($W^-$'s or their anti's for the $W^+$). An electron is envisioned as three $T$'s, a neutrino as three $V$'s, and the up- and down quark in between. All generations are considered excitations. The Higgs exists too but is not the cause of mass. It simply follows from the theory. There is a force more basic than the weak. The weak is considered an "emergent" force and there is no matter-anti-matter problem. Of course there *are* problems with this model (due to the energy having to be comprised in a very small volume, because of which potential energy and kinetic energy are comparable) and in the linked article an attempt is made to solve these.

Comment: Sorry, I expected a 'simple' or divulgative explanation, not a reference to articles. Hayashi article is from 1981, I said 'nowadays'. As I said, I'm undergraduate, I'm starting in this field, I don't understand the articles. I don't want details, I want to know what hypothesis are still plausible and some information about them.

Comment: You cannot get a course here, list of alternative models can be found in wikipediia,  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternatives_to_the_Standard_Higgs_Model#List_of_alternative_models